# How can i install new apk on a device without loosing the previous data,though a new version will be installed

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How can i install new apk on a device without loosing the previous data,though a new version will be installed

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for an app to tell if it has been uninstalled or to receive notification of it's pending uninstallation.

When an application is removed, the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` intent will be sent out to all receivers **except** for your own. Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) for more.

If you wish to tell that an app *other* than yours has been removed, you can set you app to receive `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` by adding the following to your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And creating a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        //Your code here
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ed George Let me get some more idea from your shared doc.

Answer (score -1):

while an your app is uninstalled ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED intent will be sent to all receivers **except your app which is currently uninstalled** so by another app you can know that.

Comment: Can u please elaborate more i didn't get.I am new to phone gap and i want to edit and add some contents during uninstall of an apk. Like changing the alert message and all.Can u help @divyang panchal